# Getting Around "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together"

Tags: python, numpy, error-handling, scikit-learn

The code below yields the following value error.

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (8,8) (64,)
```

It first arose when I expanded the "training" data set from 10 images to 100.  The interpreter seems to be telling me that I can't perform any coordinate-wise operations on these data points because one of the coordinate pairs is missing a value. I can't argue with that. Unfortunately, my work arounds haven't exactly worked out.  I attempted to insert an if condition followed by a continue statement (i.e., if this specific coordinate comes up, it should continue from the top of the loop). The interpreter didn't like this idea and muttered something about the truth of that statement not being as cut and dry as I thought.  It suggested I try a.any() or a.all(). I checked out examples of both, and tried placing the problematic coordinate pair in the parenthesis and in place of the "a." Both approaches got me nowhere. I'm unaware of any Python functions similar to the functions I would use in C to exclude inputs that don't meet specific criteria. Other answers pertaining to similar problems recommend changing the math one uses, but I was told that this is how I am to proceed, so I'm looking at it as an error handling problem.

Does anyone have any insight concerning how one might handle this issue? Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets

digits = datasets.load_digits()
#print the 0th image in the image database as an integer matrix
print(digits.images[0])
#plot the 0th image in the database assigning each pixel an intensity of black
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(digits.images[0], cmap = plt.cm.gray_r, interpolation = 'nearest')
plt.show()
#create training subsets of images and targets(labels)
X_train = digits.images[0:1000]
Y_train = digits.target[0:1000]
#pick a test point from images (345)
X_test = digits.images[345]
#view test data point
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(digits.images[345], cmap = plt.cm.gray_r, interpolation = 'nearest')
plt.show()
#distance
def dist(x, y):
    return np.sqrt(np.sum((x - y)**2))

#expand set of test data
num = len(X_train)
no_errors = 0
distance = np.zeros(num)
for j in range(1697, 1797):
    X_test = digits.data[j]
    for i in range(num):
        distance[i] = dist(X_train[i], X_test)
    min_index = np.argmin(distance)
    if Y_train[min_index] != digits.target[j]:
        no_errors += 1
print(no_errors)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show us where the error occurs, and some of the error stack.

Then you need to identify which arrays are causing the problem, and examine their shape.  Actually the error tells us that.  One operand is a 8x8 2d array.  The other has the same number of elements but with a 1d shape.  You may have to trace some variables back to your own code.

Just to illustrate the problem:

```
In [381]: x = np.ones((8,8),int)
In [384]: y = np.arange(64)
In [385]: x*y
...
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (8,8) (64,) 
In [386]: x[:] = y
...
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (64) into shape (8,8)
```

Since the 2 arrays have the same number of elements, a fix likely involves reshaping one or the other:

```
In [387]: x.ravel() + y
Out[387]: 
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5, ... 64])
```

or `x-y.reshape(8,8)`.

My basic point is, you need to understand what array shapes mean, and how arrays of different shape can be used together.  You don't 'get around' the error, you fix the inputs so they are 'broadcasting' compatible.

I don't think problem is with the value of a specific element.

The `truth value` error occurs when you try to test an array in a `if` context.  `if` expects a simple True or False, not an array of True/False values.

```
In [389]: if x>0:print('yes')
....
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Much appreciated. The imported modules used here are very new to me, so I'll consider your response more carefully, play with this for a while, maybe do a bit more reading on the modules this relies on (focusing on arrays and broadcast rules), and see where that gets me. Many thanks for your time!

Comment: You may need to read more about the nature of the `datasets` that `sklearns` provides you.  You may have to search other `sklearn` questions.